# android cordova : cordova.exec() undefined is not a function

Tags: android, cordova, plugins

I'm developing an android phonegap app using cordova(2.2.0). I've some custom phonegap plugins to make my app do some stuff. Now I'm facing a problem, sometime when I call :

```
alert(Cordova.exec(null, null, "custom", "setValue", localStorage.emailId));
```

****undefined value is getting popped in alert.****

Here  I called `cordova.exec` after `deviceReady()` also.still not getting any value
no exception in try-catch.
 also same for `PhoneGap.exec(....)`

I don't really understand why. Someone else experienced the same error?

Comment: ref added to config file also as
<plugin name="custom" value="com.company.Custom" />

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first and second arguments of Cordova.exec() are the success and error callback functions. You don't provide any, therefore it is normal that the Cordova.exec does not return anything.

Add something like `function() {console.log(arguments);}` for those callbacks and you'll see if the plugin works successfully.